# How to obtain hexagonal type sample from st_sample (R package sf)?

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to create some sample points from an area. The points have to give an impression of density. I want them not to be random, to avoid people thinking they are "real" observations. I want them to be hexagonal distributed across the area. How to get such a sample? `st_sample` with `type = "hexagonal"` does not do the trick.

A reproducible example:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
# this works:
nc_samples_random <- st_sample(nc[1,], 100, type = "random")
# this does not:
nc_samples_hexagonal <- st_sample(nc[1,], 100, type = "hexagonal")
```

The last line of code gives this error message:

```
Error in seq_len(nrow(xy)) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

*EDITED: See previous answer on the bottom*

I think there is a bug on `st_sample` [source code](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/master/R/sample.R). For unprojected shapes (i.e. **EPSG:4326**) the area is computed in meters whereas the `bbox` limits are taken as longitude and latitude, which gives the exception described in your question.

As long as you are fine projecting your shape you can achieve your goal. A point on that, it seems that there is some degree of randomness on `st_sample`, so if you need an exact number of points you can play with the `seed` to get the right number.

```
library(sf)
library(units)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Project shape
nc_3857 = st_transform(nc[1, ], 3857)

#Reduce a little bit via negative buffer to avoid dots on the edge
nc_3857_red = st_buffer(nc_3857, dist = set_units(-2, "km"))

#Seed and sample
set.seed(2421)
nc_samples_hexagonal <-
  st_sample(nc_3857_red, 100, type = "hexagonal")

nc_unproj = st_transform(nc_3857, 4326)
nc_samples_hexagonal_unproj = st_transform(nc_samples_hexagonal, 4326)

plot(st_geometry(nc_unproj))
plot(st_geometry(nc_samples_hexagonal_unproj), add = T)
title(main = paste("N Dots Grid =", length(nc_samples_hexagonal)))
```

[image]

#### *PREVIOUS ANSWER W/ ALTERNATIVE APPROACH*

Alternative approach for sampling non-random hexagonal points by using `st_make_grid`:

```
    library(sf)
    nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

    # Hexagonal grid
    nc_samples_hexagonal = st_make_grid(nc[1,],
                                        what = "corners",
                                        square = F,
                                        n = 20)

    # Extra: Shrink original shape to 95% to erase dots close to the edge
    polys = st_geometry(st_cast(nc[1,] , "POLYGON"))
    cntrd = st_geometry(st_centroid(polys))
    polyred = (polys - cntrd)  * 0.95 + cntrd
    st_crs(polyred) <- st_crs(nc[1,])
    nc_samples_hexagonal = nc_samples_hexagonal[st_contains(polyred,  nc_samples_hexagonal, sparse = F)]

    plot(st_geometry(nc[1,]))
    plot(st_geometry(nc_samples_hexagonal) , add = T)
```

[image: Sampled hexagonal points]

Density can be adjusted either by the `cellsize` or the `n` paramater, in the reprex  `n=20`.

Comment: Nice idea, also nice the shrinking part. How would you use this method to get coordinates for a certain amount of dots?

Comment: I opened an issue on the `sf` repo to check this: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1220