# Generating samples within an sf MULTIPOLYGON in r

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf

I'm trying to generate a set of sample points within a set of islands. I generate the coastline data as follows:

```
library(osmdata)
bb <- getbb(place_name= "Shetland")
osm_box <- opq(bbox = bb) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "coastline") %>%
  osmdata_sf()
```

And then I create an `sf` feature of MULTIPOLYGON:

```
library(sf)
coast <- osm_box$osm_lines %>% 
   st_union() %>% 
   st_line_merge() %>% 
   st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
   st_transform(27700)
```

This seems to be ok. Now when I try to generate my sample points:

```
coast %>% st_sample(1000, type= "hexagonal")
```

I get one features of geometry type POINT instead of what I expect, 1000 features of POINT all located within the MULTIPOLYGON.

```
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 396882.7 ymin: 1138217 xmax: 396882.7 ymax: 1138217
epsg (SRID):    27700
proj4string:    +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
POINT (396882.7 1138217)
```

Any ideas?!

## UPDATE

Well this seems to work:

```
# Generate a polygon of the coast line
coast <- osm_box$osm_lines %>% st_union() %>% 
  st_line_merge() %>% 
  st_polygonize() %>%
  st_transform(27700)

# Generate 100 regular spaced samples within the polygon
samples <- st_sample(coast, 100, type= "regular", exact=F)

Geometry set for 100 features 
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 396861.1 ymin: 1109326 xmax: 466072.5 ymax: 1217457
epsg (SRID):    27700
proj4string:    +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
POINT (429729.3 1177035)
POINT (446778.1 1153826)
POINT (448614.3 1193497)
POINT (431511.4 1186704)
POINT (457445.3 1203824)
```

I'm not really sure why the first chink of code didn't work as expected. Be good to know. The `st_polygonize()` function seemed to make the difference.

Comment: What's the meaning of the `type = "hexagon"` part? If you keep the default (random), you get the number of points back that you specify. I don't anything about the hexagon thing, but is that something you need?

Comment: It's the arrangement of the samples I guess. The documentation says its more of a triangular arrangement - see here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208954/how-to-obtain-hexagonal-type-sample-from-st-sample-r-package-sf - it does run if I use the default (random) - it seems to take forever though.